# C# GroupBy in query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, group-by

I have 3 data sets.
One for cars (Auto) which is attached to a brand & model (AutoType) and an Owner (Eigenaar)

```
public class Auto : BaseDbEntity
{
    public string Kleur { get; set; }
    public DateTime DatumGekocht { get; set; }
    public string Nummerplaat { get; set; }
    //relations
    public Eigenaar HuidigeEigenaar { get; set; }
    public AutoType HuidigeAutoType { get; set; }
}

public class AutoType : BaseDbEntity
{
    public string Merk { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
}

public class Eigenaar : BaseDbEntity
{
    public string Voornaam { get; set; }
    public string Achternaam { get; set; }
    public string Naam => $"{Voornaam} {Achternaam}";
}
```

I'm trying to query to get the following result:

Per Merk (brand) I would like to list all the autos (cars) with their corresponding Owner (eigenaar).

To simply get a list of all cars with corresponding owners & brands I have the following code working:

```
public List<Auto> GetAllAutosSortedByName(AutoCriteria criteria)
    {
        return GetFullyGraphedAutos()
            .Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(criteria.Name))
            .OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList();
    }

private IQueryable<Auto> GetFullyGraphedAutos()
    {
        return _entityContext.Autos
            .Include(x => x.HuidigeAutoType)
            .Include(x => x.HuidigeEigenaar);
    }
```

My question is how I group them by brand (merk). I've tried something along the lines of this:

```
public List<Auto> GetAllMerkenSortedByMerk(AutoCriteria criteria)
    {
        return GetFullyGraphedAutos()
            .Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(criteria.Name))
            .GroupBy(x => x.HuidigeAutoType.Merk)
            .ToList();
    }
```

Obviously this doesn't work but I don't know how else I should query this.

Here's a visual representation: The top table being what I currently have working and the bottom one being the wanted result.

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you want to do a `.Where(x => x.Brand == "Merk")`.

Comment: No I'm sorry that might be confusing. "Merk" is just the translation of "Brand" in my language. I'm trying to group all the cars by their corresponding brand (aka merk)

Comment: What is AutoCriteria? And why are you filtering the returned IQueryable from GetFullyGraphedAutos by the name of criteria being empty?

Comment: Can I just confirm what you want returned. You say you want them grouped by brand but your method expects a list of autos to be returned not a list of auto 'groups'. Do you just want them still in a flat list but ordered so that all brands are grouped together?

Comment: I have made a visual representation of the result I want to reach:
https://gyazo.com/ae1ef87bc14af97cedd998b596c18adf
The top table is what I currently have. To bottom one is what I'd like to achieve by grouping.

Comment: You don't want to "group" the vehicles by brand, you want to "sort" the vehicles by brand.

Comment: Wouldn't that make a single brand show more then once? I want a brand to show only once with multiple cars listed under it.

Comment: Your method has a return type of List<Auto> it's a flat list. I think the implementation of your method using the group By is correct you just need to change the return type of the method to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should apply `select` after grouping action and you can't select the desired data with `Auto` collection. Create model classes to achieve it;

```
public class GroupMerks
{
    public string Merk;

    public IEnumerable<Owner> Owners { get; set; }
}

public class Owner
{
    public string Plate { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then modify the query like this;

```
public List<GroupMerks> GetAllMerkenSortedByMerk(AutoCriteria criteria)
{
    return GetFullyGraphedAutos()
        .Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(criteria.Name))
        .GroupBy(x => x.HuidigeAutoType.Merk)
        .Select(x => new GroupMerks
        {
            Merk = x.Key,
            Owners = x.Select(s => new Owner
            {
                Plate = s.Nummerplaat,
                Name = s.HuidigeEigenaar.Achternaam
            })
        })
        .ToList();
}
```

**Sample Output:**

```
[
   {
      "Merk":"Ford",
      "Owners":[
         {
            "Plate":"123ABC",
            "Name":"John"
         },
         {
            "Plate":"112CDE",
            "Name":"Mark"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "Merk":"BMW",
      "Owners":[
         {
            "Plate":"223ABE",
            "Name":"Steve"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```